# SpeechRecognitionEngine stops working when I have focus in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm using `SpeechRecognitionEngine` to recognize speech in a WPF application. The app is using a small custom grammar and tries to detect words asynchronously, using `RecognizeMode.Multiple`.

The problem is that if I click inside a TextBox control that I've placed onto the interface, the recognizer works for two or three more words and then stops running.
In the application's output window, I can see about 4 threads being closed.

If I don't click in the TextBox, everything works fine; I can even click outside the app's window, onto Notepad or something, and the recognition still works.

I'm using Windown 7 Home Premium x64 and Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
try
{
    var c = new Choices();

    c.Add("copy");
    c.Add("cut");
    c.Add("paste");
    c.Add("delete");
    c.Add("select all");
    c.Add("compile");
    c.Add("refactor");
    c.Add("spellcheck");
    c.Add("exit");

    var gb = new GrammarBuilder(c);
    var g = new Grammar(gb);

    SpeechRecognitionEngine recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(g);

    recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized +=
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec_SpeechRecognized);

    recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
       MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
}


private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Result.Text + " ");
}
```

Comment: WPF supports speech recognition, bound to get in the way.  Check the InputMethod.SpeechMode property.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the tip. I've set this property to each of its supported values, but there doesn't seem to be any difference, the problem remains the same.